# Best way to log binary data on logcat

Tags: android, logcat

For debugging purposes I am currently writing some code that logs the contents of an HTTP response (headers, response code, body) on logcat.

In case that the body of the response contains binary data I would like to log the body in a way that I can reconstruct the data by copying it with ctrl-c from the logcat window in Android Studio and then paste it in another tool like a hex editor.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not write the binary content to a file?

Comment: @CommonsWare The project that I work currently for maintains a library that is used in all kind of apps of different app publishers. So I need a simple mechanism that helps me with "remotely debugging" their issues. The easiest way to do this is "get me copy of the logcat".

Comment: Hmmmm... then you might need to work backwards from your hex editor (or other tool) and see what it accepts for clipboard content that will be useful for you. For example, perhaps it supports decoding base64-encoded binary content.

Comment: In the end I ended up with base64 encoding as suggested by CommonsWare which my favorite text editor notepad++ can turn easily in binary data.